# How to I get YTD to work over multiple hierarchies

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I have a Dimension `[Time]` on my cube. I have the following properties on my time dimension.

1. Date `&[2015/12/25]`
2. Month `&[2015/12]`
3. Year `&[2015]`
4. Week `&[2015wk52]`

Arranged into 2 hierarchies.

`[Time].[Y - M - D]`

- Year
- Month
- Date

and

`[Time].[Y - WK]`

- Year
- Week
- Date

I also created a measure

```
[Measures].[Foo YTD] AS
AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Foo])
```

This seems to work great when I use the `Y M D` dimension in excel. But when I use the `Y WK` hierarchy, all my weeks return the same data.

What am I doing wrong?

My attribute relations should be correctly setup I think.

Comment: did you check the settings I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @whytheq Period to date works fine... It seems YTD works on a default hierarchy...>_<

Comment: ok - but is the attribute you are feeding into the `YTD` function set to type year in SSAS ? If it is not typed correctly in SSAS then this function will not work.

Comment: hi Aron - did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe your problem.

In the definition of the `YTD` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146039.aspx

It has this remark:

> the Ytd function is a shortcut function for the PeriodsToDate function
>   where the Type property of the attribute hierarchy on which the level
>   is based is set to Years.

You could prove that this is your problem by trying the `PeriodsToDate` option - if it then works you know that it is the attribute type that is to blame.